# Retreiving sorted data by date with Room and Paging 3

Tags: android, android-room, android-paging-3

When I get the list that is stored I get this pattern

`["12/08/2021", "12/07/2021", "12/08/2020", "11/07/2021", "11/05/2021"]`

As you see the month and day are being sorted, but it looks like the year is not being read.

below is Query that I'm using with Room

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM timeSheet ORDER BY date DESC")
    fun timeSheetsByDate(): PagingSource<Int, TimeSheet>
```

[Here is a video of it](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4177453/145260559-9e8fd332-a6a3-4f2e-b73b-94344ebe9aa0.mov)

I then tried with the **@TypeConverters**,

```
  @Query("SELECT * FROM timeSheet ORDER BY date(date) DESC")
    fun timeSheetsByDate(): PagingSource<Int, TimeSheet>
```

```
@Entity(tableName = "timeSheet")
data class TimeSheet(
    @PrimaryKey var id: String = "",

    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    @TypeConverters(TimestampConverter::class)
    var dateSubmitted: String? = null
 
)

class TimestampConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromTimestamp(value: Long?): Date? {
        return if (value == null) null else Date(value)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToTimestamp(dateString: String?): Date {

        val format = TimeFormatter()

        val date = Calendar.getInstance()
        date.time = format.date(dateString)!!

        return date.time
    }
}
```

but for some reason when refreshing the data for the second time it doesn't show the values from the first page, so I have to scroll down until all the data is fully loaded and then when I scroll up again I'm able to see the values from the first page.

[Here is a video of it](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4177453/145261230-5e8ee15c-3b35-4b27-b295-ca854c31f803.mov)

Comment: I didn't check thoroughly, but make sure the string you send to date() in SQLlite is one of the compatible formats: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

IIRC DD/MM/YYYY will not work, and I have no idea what happens with TimeFormatter :)

Comment: It looks to me like the sorting is out of whack and you may want to check what the initial key you are passing to `Pager` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM timeSheet ORDER BY substr(date,7,4)||substr(date,4,2)||substr(1,2) DESC")
```

However, that is awkward.

It is strongly suggested that you do not use dd/mm/yyyy to store the timestamp but instead store it in a [recognised format](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html#time_values) e.g. yyyy-mm-dd

You can then sort and compare dates and also make use of the [date and time functions](https://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) that are built into SQLite.

Your TypeConverters will not be used by Room (and would not work). Room expects a TypeConverter to convert from an unknown type to an underlying type known/handled by Room.

Having `var dateSubmitted: String? = null` means that the type is String and room can handle storing a String without it being converted, there is no need to convert it and therefore Room won't convert it.

If however you had `var dateSubmitted: Date? = null`

Then Room does not know how to handle the Date type and will then demand a TypeConverter to convert the Date type into a type that Room can handle. It would also need a second TypeConverter to be able to convert the type stored in the database into a Date type when extracting data.

If you want to use a recognised format, say YYYY-MM-DD then a String can hold that and no TypeConverter is required as far as Room is concerned. However, you need to provide the date as a string in that format for use by Room and handle Room returning the TimeSheet with YYYY-MM-DD in the dateSubmitted member/field.

I would suggest considering the following demonstration of TypeConverters :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "timeSheet")
@TypeConverters(TimestampConverter::class) /* due to scoping TypeConveters needs to be here or at @Database level */
data class TimeSheet(
    @PrimaryKey var id: String = "",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "date")
    var dateSubmitted: Date? = null,
)
{
    companion object {
        val format = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    }
}

class TimestampConverter {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromDateToString(value: Date): String {
        return format.format(value)
    }
    @TypeConverter
    fun toDateFromString(value: String) : Date {
        return format.parse(value)
    }
}
```

and your original query would then work.

For example using the above along with :-

```
@Dao
interface AllDao {

    @Insert
    fun insert(timeSheet: TimeSheet): Long
    @Query("SELECT * FROM timeSheet ORDER BY date DESC")
    fun getTimeSheetsOrderedByDateSubmittedDesc(): List<TimeSheet>
}
```

and :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AllDao
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getAllDao()


        /* ["12/08/2021", "12/07/2021", "12/08/2020", "11/07/2021", "11/05/2021"] */
        dao.insert(TimeSheet("A",TimeSheet.format.parse("2021-08-12")))
        dao.insert(TimeSheet("B",TimeSheet.format.parse("2021-07-12")))
        dao.insert(TimeSheet("C",TimeSheet.format.parse("2021-05-11")))
        dao.insert(TimeSheet("D",TimeSheet.format.parse("2020-08-12")))
        dao.insert(TimeSheet("E",TimeSheet.format.parse("2021-07-11")))

        for (t: TimeSheet in dao.getTimeSheetsOrderedByDateSubmittedDesc()) {
            Log.d("RESULTINFO","ID = ${t.id} DateSubmitted = ${t.dateSubmitted} or ${TimestampConverter().fromDateToString(t.dateSubmitted!!)}")
        }
    }
}
```

Then the resultant output is :-

```
2021-12-09 09:20:55.299 D/RESULTINFO: ID = A DateSubmitted = Thu Aug 12 00:00:00 GMT+10:00 2021 or 2021-08-12
2021-12-09 09:20:55.299 D/RESULTINFO: ID = B DateSubmitted = Mon Jul 12 00:00:00 GMT+10:00 2021 or 2021-07-12
2021-12-09 09:20:55.300 D/RESULTINFO: ID = E DateSubmitted = Sun Jul 11 00:00:00 GMT+10:00 2021 or 2021-07-11
2021-12-09 09:20:55.300 D/RESULTINFO: ID = C DateSubmitted = Tue May 11 00:00:00 GMT+10:00 2021 or 2021-05-11
2021-12-09 09:20:55.300 D/RESULTINFO: ID = D DateSubmitted = Wed Aug 12 00:00:00 GMT+10:00 2020 or 2020-08-12
```

Comment: I went for the format change instead.  I just had to change the format to```YYYY-MM-DD``` this way I don't have to add the converter as you mentioned.

Comment: @JohnDelacruz imo you chose the better way.